# How could I apply an observable to a checkbox to verify if it is selected and thus be able to reload my application page?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Good afternoon I have a query, I want to automatically reload the page every 1 minute of my application if a checkbox is selected, so if it is not selected, the option to update the page automatically is deactivated, I try to do it through javascript capturing the event with change, but I can't make the page reload automatically, using setTimeout, so I would like to know if there is another way to do this operation through an observable one and how it would be, since I am still new in angular yet.

Then I put the code that I have done so far:

Code HTML

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="checkCheckBoxvalue($event)">Check me!</mat-checkbox>
```

Code Typescipt

```
checkCheckBoxvalue(event){
      console.log(event.checked)
      if (event.checked){
         this.com=true
        }
      else{
        this.com=false
      }  

      if (this.com) {
        console.log("The checkbox is active")
        setInterval(function(){
             // ... function to reload my page
          }, 1000);
      }

      else {
        console.log("The checbox is not active")
      }
```

**UPDATE**

The arrow function must be added to obtain the desired result

```
  loadpaginator(): any {
      this.dataSource.loadData(
          this.id_interface ? this.id_interface.toString():undefined,   
          this.EquipoOrigenValue ? this.EquipoOrigenValue:undefined,   // esta linea represta un condicional conjugado en una sola linea. 
          this.LocalidadOrigenValue ? this.LocalidadOrigenValue:undefined,
          this.VendedorValue ? this.VendedorValue:undefined,
          this.id_prtg?this.id_prtg.toString():undefined,
          this.CategoriaOrigenValue ? this.CategoriaOrigenValue:undefined,
          this.EquipoDestinoValue?this.EquipoDestinoValue:undefined,
          this.OspfOperValue?this.OspfOperValue:undefined,
          this.OspfAdminValue?this.OspfAdminValue:undefined,
          this.ServicioValue?this.ServicioValue:undefined,
          this.TipoOrigenValue?this.TipoOrigenValue:undefined,
          this.PuertoOrigenValue?this.PuertoOrigenValue:undefined,
          this.paginator.pageSize,
          (this.paginator.pageIndex + 1)
      );
    }
```

So now my table is updated from time to time, depending on what I specify in the function setInterval ():

```
.......
      if (event) {
        console.log("The checkbox is active");
        this.timeout = setInterval(()=>{
          this.loadpaginator()
        }, 5000);
      }
.....
```

Comment: Maybe you want to change `function()` to a lambda `() =>`, the former introduces some scoping issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this:

`<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="isChecked" 
               (change)="checkCheckBoxvalue(isChecked)">Check me!</mat-checkbox>`

Add variable `timeout` on top

`timeout;`

```
checkCheckBoxvalue(event: any){ 
if (event) {
  console.log("The checkbox is active");
  this.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    // ... function to reload my page
  }, 1000);
}
else {
  console.log("The checbox is not active");
  clearTimeout(this.timeout);
}
```

And if you want to reload the page, later you will learn about Router. This is the best way to do this.

Good luck

Comment: Friend update my question because it gave me an error when using the function in my case specifically, but thank you very much.

Comment: Better ask about it in next question, and give more code info